# Mystery word indicating a body part in a medical book published in 1563

Tags: medical, middle-english

The following title is written in a book by surgeon T. Gale published in 1563. I have trouble translating the last word: "Of woundes of the [x]".

Mainly the second letter after "B" is blank for me, B?ESTE...

[image]

Comment: "Of woundes in the breste"? It doesn't look like an 'r', but I don't see what else it could possibly be.

Comment: I would wonder if it is "woundes in the belle (belly)".  Though "breaste" is also a strong contender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is *Breste*. The 'r' is an *r rotunda*, examples and the explanation of which can be found in [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_rotunda)

[image: r rotunda from Malmesbury bible]
*r rotunda from Malmesbury bible, from Wikipedia*

It was used when the letter 'r' followed a letter with a rounded stroke, like that in a capital 'B'. The Wikipedia articlehas several other variations of the *r rotunda*, which include ones with a descender below the 'r' (like your example seems to have, unless that's just a blotch).

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with Peter Shor:

"Of woundes in the breste."

As I'm sure you are aware, this translates to "... wounds in the chest" in modern English.